# clear input texts affect Angular filter

Tags: angularjs, html

I made a form that returns data from database using Angular and web API.

Inside of the form there's an Angular filter. Another Angular clears every input texts in the form,
 the problem is when I click the button I must reload the page to get data.

Do you have any way to clear input texts without affecting the filter and not to reload data ? or to keep data on page.

OR how to make a function to clear input texts.

```
<form >
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Hide" />Hide **<input type="button" value="Clear" ng-click="Code='';Latin='';Local='';Nhd='';Ndw='';Num=''" />** <input type="submit" value="Save" ng-click="save()"/>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contract Type</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Code</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="10" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" title="Alphnumeric" autofocus ng-model="Code.Staff_Type_Code"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Latin Description</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="35" ng-model="Latin.L_Desc"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Local Description</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="35" ng-model="Local.A_Desc"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No. Of Houres Per Day</td>
                <td><input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]+$" title="Please enter numbers only" size="10" maxlength="2" ng-model="Nhd"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No. Of Days Per Week(s)</td>
                <td><input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]+$" title="Please enter numbers only" size="10" maxlength="2" ng-model="Ndw"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>End Of Contract By</td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option ng-model="Age">Age</option>
                        <option ng-model="NYears">Number Of Years in Service</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Number</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]+$" title="Please enter numbers only" size="10" maxlength="2" ng-model="Num">
                    <select>
                        <option ng-model="Months">Months</option>
                        <option ng-model="Years">Years</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </fieldset>

    <br />

    <table border="1" ng-hide="Hide">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Latin Description</th>
                <th>Local Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="c in Contracts | filter:Code | filter:Latin | filter:Local   track by $index">

                <td>{{c.Staff_Type_Code}}</td>
                <td>{{c.L_Desc}}</td>
                <td>{{c.A_Desc}}</td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Edit" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the resetting for particular form fields:-

Step 1:-Have a link/button on-clicking it resetForm() is triggered

```
<button ng-click="resetForm()">Reset Input Texts</button>
```

Step 2:- In your controller, define resetForm() method

```
 $scope.resetForm = function() {
    $scope.Code={};
    $scope.Latin ={};
    //Add all those fields which you want to reset
  };
```

Cheers !!

Comment: But there are three input texts wrote inside it  [object Object], how to remove it kindly

Comment: If you want to remove them individually, not complete object, then you can use  $scope.Code.Staff_Type_Code  = null;

Comment: It works but I must reload the page to fill the HTML table from db. i am just wondring why the [object Object] is not appearing in some input texts, do you have a way to keep the data in the HTML table. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to keep the initial data in table after form reset?

Comment: yes i want to keep the loaded data shown in the HTML table to able the user to re-filter or insert new record

Comment: it works like this but i dont understand why                                                                $scope.resetform = function () {
        $scope.Code = {};
        $scope.Latin = {};
        $scope.Local = {};
        $scope.Nhd = null;
        $scope.Ndw = null;
        $scope.Num = null;
        }